# Vue $attrs fallthrough attribute: How can I use intellisense to get suggestions for the properties of the attributes?

Tags: vue.js, visual-studio-code, intellisense

So in Vue, you can pass props between components by writing `v-bind="$attrs"`. Then, you can use these props by saying, for instance `{{ this.$attrs.somePropsHere }}`. It would be ideal if I can get suggestions as soon as I start typing `this.$attrs.`, as it always is with Intellisense. But unfortunately I can't. Any ideas on how to make this work, if such a functionality exists?

Comment: What exactly should it be completed with? Fallthrough attributes can be anything. Aren't supposed to be used explicitly in the template, `{{ this.$attrs.somePropsHere }}` , also `this` isn't needed

Comment: We are talking about intellisense. Can I get suggestions when I type this.$attrs. or even $attrs. ?

Comment: You shouldn't, it's unknown. You probably misuse attrs. Anything typed should go to props